# Add a "resize handle" on the bottom right corner UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, window-resize

I am currently developing a UWP application using C# and XAML on VS pro. The thing is I would like to add a small resize handle on the bottom right corner similar to the one we had in W32 apps.

I cannot find any similar option apart from "GridSplitter".This is not the same thing but I believe could be applied somehow as a resize handle since this feature is used to resize the window grid.

[Resize Handle Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co8PQ.png)

The purpose of this handle is so users can easily resize windows using their finger.

Thanks for reading. Any suggestion would be more than welcome.

Please do not hesitate to request me more details or information.

Cheers

Comment: The UWP window itself has this capability. When you drag the bottom right corner, you could resize the window. If you mean you want to resize the Grid when drag the bottom right corner, you could think about [Manipulation events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/touch-interactions#manipulation-events).

Comment: Thanks Xavier for your answer. The idea is to resize the window. What I am looking for is a large landing zone for the finger so there is no room for error.

Comment: Have you checked the [Manipulation events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/touch-interactions#manipulation-events) to see if it meets you requirement?